# How to override a default value to a non default one

Tags: python, overriding, odoo, default, odoo-12

I want to override the `picking_type_id` value in `purchase.order` to be non default value. I tried doing this but it's not working:

```
_columns = {
    'picking_type_id': fields.many2one('stock.picking.type', 'Deliver To', help="This will determine picking type of incoming shipment", required=False, states={'confirmed': [('readonly', False)], 'approved': [('readonly', False)], 'done': [('readonly', True)]}),
} 
_defaults = {
    'picking_type_id': False
}
```

Comment: Try refer the below link :
https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-to-replace-default-picking-type-id-on-purchase-order-without-change-the-original-module-purchase-by-inherit-82435

Comment: Are you sure you're on Odoo 12? You're using the old API which is not useable since Odoo 10 anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The default `picking_type_id` value comes from the window action. You can find all the window actions in the [stock_picking_views](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/stock/views/stock_picking_views.xml#L436) file.

Use the `default` attribute to set a default value, for example:

```
state = fields.Selection([
        ('draft','Draft'),
        ('open', 'Open'),
        ('in_payment', 'In Payment'),
        ('paid', 'Paid'),
        ('cancel', 'Cancelled'),
    ], string='Status', default='draft')
```

To override the default value whatever where it is defined you can redefine the `default_get` method. Try the following code:

```py
class StockPicking(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.picking'

    @api.model
    def default_get(self, fields_list):
        res = super(StockPicking, self).default_get(fields_list)
        res['picking_type_id'] = False
        return res
```

Comment: thank you so much , actually the problem was on my odoo configuration ,i had a default value for picking_type_id that kept filling it